# signing firefox extension

Tags: c#, firefox-addon

guys I need some help for days now I have been looking for a way for signing firefox XPI file,
but i didn't found any thing that works ( including here ) the posts I found where very old,
and not compadiable with new firefox version.

does any body here know how to?

thanks in advance.
p.s
I want to write a packer\signer in c#

edit:
im using mcCoy CA that MDN says valid.
i know there is a python script that sign add ons but i dont know pyton so please advice something else and for that matter i preferably dont watnt to use java...

Comment: By "a Python script" you probably mean [mine](http://adblockplus.org/blog/signing-firefox-extensions-with-python-and-m2crypto)? My blog post links to a description of the signature format, you can use any programming language to create the signature. Which part do you have problems with? Stack Overflow is the place to ask questions, not to have code written for you.

Comment: im looking 4 directions not the answer, i have tried so many diffrent things none worked, all i need is some one who done this with mccoy CA ( right now i dont want to spend money on this.... ) .
thanks for the response any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for a code example in Java, there is [XPISigner](http://code.google.com/p/xpisigner/). However, its source code seems rather complicated, you might have better chances if you look at the [signature format description](http://o-regan.org/2007/04/11/firefox-xpi-internal-structure/) and the [simple Python example script](http://adblockplus.org/blog/signing-firefox-extensions-with-python-and-m2crypto). It is mostly simple, the "complicated" part is only generating a detached RSA signature of the `META-INF/zigbert.sf` file (stored in `META-INF/zigbert.rsa`). Note that `META-INF/zigbert.rsa` has to be the first file in the XPI archive.

Comment: i dont want to work with java, im working on an infarstructure in c#, and trying to avoid importting assemblies from other languages. right now i only need the how to sign an extenssion, and xpisigner is obselte from FF 4+ and thats not good 4 me.